# How to add a buzzer to my python project?

Tags: python, machine-learning, face-detection

I have made a face mask detection program using machine learning with the help of a online tutorial on youtube. I have made the program and it works good but i wanted to add a buzzer that beeps whenever the person isn't actually wearing a mask. I want the buzzer to buzz through the actual speakers. This is the code for the detection:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os

def detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet):
(h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (224, 224),
    (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
faceNet.setInput(blob)
detections = faceNet.forward()
print(detections.shape)
faces = []
locs = []
preds = []
for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
    if confidence > 0.5:
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
        (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
        (endX, endY) = (min(w - 1, endX), min(h - 1, endY))
        face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
        face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
        face = img_to_array(face)
        face = preprocess_input(face)
        faces.append(face)
        locs.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))
if len(faces) > 0:
    faces = np.array(faces, dtype="float32")
    preds = maskNet.predict(faces, batch_size=32)
return (locs, preds)


prototxtPath = r"face_detector\deploy.prototxt"
weightsPath = r"face_detector\res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)
maskNet = load_model("mask_detector.model")
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
while True:
frame = vs.read()
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
(locs, preds) = detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet)
for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
(startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
(mask, withoutMask) = pred
label = "Mask" if mask > withoutMask else "No Mask"
color = (0, 255, 0) if label == "Mask" else (0, 0, 255)
label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(mask, withoutMask) * 100)
cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)

cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

if key == ord("q"):
    break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use the `winsound` module:

```
import winsound
winsound.Beep(frequency_in_hz, duration_in_ms)
```

And on Linux, you should be able to do this by printing `\a`

```
print('\a')
```